# Add constant to each element of ListOfPoints in openCV Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am finding the contours only on part of a frame (below the horizon line) . I want to have real coordinates of the points after I use `MatOfPoint.toList()`. This is the code I have:

```
Iterator<MatOfPoint> itr = mContours.iterator(); 
    while(itr.hasNext()){

    MatOfPoint tmp = itr.next();
    List<Point> listOfPoints = tmp.toList();            

    Iterator<Point> iterator = listOfPoints.iterator();         
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Point p = iterator.next();
        p.y=p.y+CONSTANT;      
    }           
}
```

The problem is: It's **very slow**. Is there any way to do it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not add the offset already when calling findContours ?

http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#findContours(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20java.util.List,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int,%20org.opencv.core.Point)

( you'd just give it as the last arg there )